# Laravel email verification link issue

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, email-verification

In my laravel application's app url is something like this, `admin.site` and I'm  registering users to my application from the admin panel.

And my client portal url is `customer.site`.

Once the admin creates an user from admin panel (admin.site) customer receive an account verification email. But the issue is now I need this verification link to be

```
customer.site/email/...
```

but the current link is like this

```
admin.site/email/...
```

So how can I change this verification link to `customer.site`

Following is my store function for customer controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required','email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
            'mobile'=>['required', 'regex:/^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{8})$/','numeric','min:9'],
            'username'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:10', 'unique:users'],   
            'roles'=>['required'],
            'user_roles'=>['required'],
        ]);

        //Customer::create($request->all());

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        event(new Registered($user));

        return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                        ->with('success','Customer created successfully. Verification email has been sent to user email.  ');
    }
```

I'm sending my verification email

```
event(new Registered($user));
```

As the customers have no access to the admin site it gives me 403 error message.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use?

Comment: @CollinI have updated the question, here event(new Registered($user)); this will send the verification mail to the user when the user is being created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an application that might send a lot of emails it is usefull to use notifcations for emails. 
An notifaction can be created by executing the following command:

```
php artisan make:notification SendRegisterEmailNotifcation
```

This command wil create a **SendRegisterEmailNotifcation** file that can be found by navigating to the ***app/Notifications/SendRegisterEmailNotifcation.php*** path.
When you have done that and have customized the message, action and other possible things your store function would look like this.
I've removed the validation and put it in a request. If you're intrested in how it works a example can found below.

More information on notifcations can be found here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-notification-system-on-slack-and-email/

```
// CustomerController
public function store(StoreCustomerRequest $request)
{
    // Get input from the request and hash the password
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

    // Create user and assign role
    $user = User::create($input);
    $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

    // Send Register Email
    $user->notify(new SendRegisterEmailNotifcation);

     return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                        ->with('success','Customer created successfully. Verification email has been sent to user email.  ');
}
```

I would recommend creating Requests for validating the data. That way the controller will stay cleaner and you actually validate the data where laravel intended it to. 
//StoreCustomerRequest

```
class StoreCustomerRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // @todo Add validation rules
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha|min:2|max:255'
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ];
    }
}
```

Add the notifiable to your Customer Model. This has to be done to be able to send a notificaiton.

```
// Customer model
class Customer {
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Comment: @colin am getting this error now, Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SendRegisterEmailNotification' not found

Comment: yes i did, and i called $user->notify(new SendRegisterEmailNotification()); in my stroe method instead of event(new Registered($user));

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev Did you use a use statement to include the class?

Comment: yes i have added use App\Http\Notifications\SendRegisterEmailNotification; on my controller

Comment: @Collin I think my import path is incorrect, can you tell me what would be the correct path to use it in the cotroller, this is the path for the class, App\Notifications\SendRegisterEmailNotification

Comment: @Collin Please check your last comment, I think it has a confusing typo. (Actually two, but I get the shortcut "U"...)

Comment: @Collin i'm already using it, use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev Where is the use statement located; top of file, or just inside the controller's class?

Comment: I've changed my awnser, check it out. Let me know if you run into any probnlems

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica it's on the top of the controller

Comment: Add it to the model, like i mentioned in the awnser

Comment: @Collin i'm already using the use Notifiable; inside the customer module.. in my controller I have this, use App\Notifications\SendRegisterEmailNotification; but still this gives me an error saying, Class 'App\Notifications\SendRegisterEmailNotification' not found

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev Top of the file, or top of the controller's class?  Please edit your code if you're not going to be clear.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica it's on top of the file

Comment: @Collin I fixed the issue, email is sending now, but now the thing is how to set the verification link with the tokens